# R: Loop in R, object not found

Tags: r, loops, object

My purporse is to find vector s, but the result is object y not found.
Note that data.nbin is a vector(,10).

```
set.seed(124)
data.nbin<-rnbinom(n=10,size=6.230651,mu=77.896194)
prob=6.23065/(6.23065+77.896194)
t=10.25
```

Please kindly help me to fix this. Thanks a lot

```
for (i in (1:10)) {
  y[i]<-data.nbin[i]
  for (j in (1:length(y[i]))){
  time.happen<-runif(y[i],min = 0,max=10.25)
  time.report<-rexp(y[i],rate=0.2587)
  matrix<-cbind(time.happen,time.report)
  index<-which((ifelse(matrix[,2] >= 10.25,1,0)) !=0, TRUE)
  t=length(index)
  i=i
  for (o in (1:length(index))){
                c=rlnorm(1, 14.4257740, 0.7897719)
                u=(time.report[index]-10.25)
                ct=((1+0.05)^(u))*c
                }
  s[i]=sum(ct)}
  return(s[i])
}
```

Comment: you need to first set the variable `y`. such as `y=list()` or else your line `y[i]<-data.nbin[i]` will have cause an error.

Comment: Because y is not defined. Put this before the forloop: `y <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 10)`